# Creating a sequential child - child process in c

Tags: c

I wish to create a sequential process that will create a specified number of children. For example if parent process ID is 769 the process will be as follows:

```
769(parent) -> 770(first child) -> 771(grand child) ... -> xx (n*grand child)
```

based on the number of children I want. PID of the children doesn't matter as long as they are sequential and have no siblings.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    int iterations;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: forkloop <iterations>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    iterations = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

    int n = fork();
    for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        if(n == 0) {
            printf("ppid = %d, pid = %d, i = %d\n", getppid(), getpid(), i);
            n = fork();
        }
        if (n < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }
       //printf("ppid = %d, pid = %d, i = %d\n", getppid(), getpid(), i);
    }
    // printf("ppid = %d, pid = %d\n", getppid(), getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

I have made this but I believe this is a bit wrong. Could anyone help out?

Comment: You can't guarantee that the child processes will have consecutive numbers; some other process could also spawn children and grab one of the numbers you hoped for.  On some systems (ones running in a more secure mode), the child PIDs are deliberately randomized.

Comment: Oh yes I don't mind the numbers to be same or consecutive, i just need to create n number of child - child processes with no siblings

Comment: Do you want PID 769 to be the parent of each of 770, 771, 772, ... or do you want 769 to be the parent of 770, and 770 to be the parent of 771, and 771 to be the parent of 772, ...?  You need to ensure that your processes exit at appropriate points — wait for (all) their offspring to perish (the kids will all commit suicide; it's a morbid business!).  —— Judging from your update, you classified 771 as 'second child' but it is 'second generation' or 'grandchild' rather than sibling to 770.

Comment: the latter is exactly what I want, 770 to be parent of 771, 771 to be parent of 772 etc,

Comment: i hope its clear now

Comment: "No siblings". Why?

Answer (score 1):

Think through the logic carefully.  You're close, but need to get closer.  This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: forkloop <iterations>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int iterations = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    if (iterations < 1 || iterations > 20)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid iterations %d (1..20 allowed)\n", iterations);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Initial process: PID %d (parent %d)\n", (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
    fflush(stdout);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
        {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (pid == 0)
        {
            /* Child - report ID */
            printf("ppid = %d, pid = %d, i = %d\n", getppid(), getpid(), i);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        if (pid != 0)
        {
            /* Parent - break loop and wait for kid (and grandkid, and ...) to die */
            break;
        }
    }

    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    {
        printf("PID %d: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n",
               (int)getpid(), corpse, status);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return i;
}
```

(There's no guarantee that `pid_t` returned by `getpid()` et al is actually an `int`, though it is normally equivalent.  I added the casts to ensure there is no problem, though in practice you can get away without them.  The last `fflush()` is not strictly needed; the process exits which flushes the output anyway.  The earlier ones are a good idea; you could get confusing output if they were absent and the output of the program was piped to some process to capture it.  Before you `fork()`, it's a good idea to have no pending output — so `fflush(0)` aka `fflush(NULL)` is perhaps a good idea, in general, though here it isn't necessary.)

Sample outputs (source code `kids17.c`, program name `kids17`):

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes kids17.c -o kids17 
$ kids17
Usage: forkloop <iterations>
$ kids17 4
Initial process: PID 2686 (parent 888)
ppid = 2686, pid = 2687, i = 0
ppid = 2687, pid = 2688, i = 1
ppid = 2688, pid = 2689, i = 2
ppid = 2689, pid = 2690, i = 3
PID 2689: child 2690 exited with status 0x0400
PID 2688: child 2689 exited with status 0x0300
PID 2687: child 2688 exited with status 0x0200
PID 2686: child 2687 exited with status 0x0100
$ …some work done…
$ kids17 10
Initial process: PID 2704 (parent 888)
ppid = 2704, pid = 2705, i = 0
ppid = 2705, pid = 2706, i = 1
ppid = 2706, pid = 2707, i = 2
ppid = 2707, pid = 2708, i = 3
ppid = 2708, pid = 2709, i = 4
ppid = 2709, pid = 2710, i = 5
ppid = 2710, pid = 2711, i = 6
ppid = 2711, pid = 2712, i = 7
ppid = 2712, pid = 2713, i = 8
ppid = 2713, pid = 2714, i = 9
PID 2713: child 2714 exited with status 0x0A00
PID 2712: child 2713 exited with status 0x0900
PID 2711: child 2712 exited with status 0x0800
PID 2710: child 2711 exited with status 0x0700
PID 2709: child 2710 exited with status 0x0600
PID 2708: child 2709 exited with status 0x0500
PID 2707: child 2708 exited with status 0x0400
PID 2706: child 2707 exited with status 0x0300
PID 2705: child 2706 exited with status 0x0200
PID 2704: child 2705 exited with status 0x0100
$
```

I didn't have any other processes actively spawning child processes while I was running this testing.